# TableView indexPathForRowAtPoint returns row index 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have problem with receiving right `NSIndexPath` in gesture recognizer selector.
In `UITableViewController:viewDidLoad` im initializing gesture recognizer

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = 
        [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
```

In gesture handler im trying to get row index:

```
- (void) swipeRight: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
    NSInteger row = swipedIndexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"Row %d", swipedIndexPath.row);
}
```

CGPoint is correct but row is always 0. Any idea why ?

Comment: is tableView valid, visible and filled with rows?

Comment: yes it is valid, because if i call self.tableView:setEditing i get expected behaviour (each cell gets "-" button for deletion).

Comment: Do you have multiple sections?  How many rows does each section have?  Log the swipedIndexPath.section also.

Comment: Yes i have multiple sections which are handled by NSFetchResultController. Most of the times one section is visible only as i use same field in predicate and as a sectionNameKeyPath of initWithFetchRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to each **UITableViewCell** (with same selector). Then when the selector is called you can get the cell via: `sender.view`.

Comment: If i dont figure out how to do it via tableview ill try your suggestion.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having a similar issue.  If I swipe an empty cell it returns "0" index which is a valid indexPath.row but the wrong one.